# URL link auto added 9443 port which block https request

Tags: nginx, web, proxy, webserver, nat

We have a web server behind nginx proxy server and nat server, architecture just like this:
[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdQCt.png)

When users access out web server through https://a.com with browser in public network, the URL will auto add 9443 port, and the URL would change to https://a.com:9443 with 302 redirect http code.

We have try access https://a.com through nginx proxy server, without the nat server, and it work fine, user can access https://a.com successful.
Once through our NAT server, the URL will become https://a.com:9443, which block the request, and user's access would be failed.

Is the NAT server question, or the Web server question?